# Using user input in an array with integers and string. I want to show an error message to the user if the format is not valid

Tags: c#, arrays

Everything is fine until the user uses the wrong format. I can’t use the null function because it isn't null; it's just not the expected format. How can I fix this? I'm still learning and am fairly new to this.

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(@"Introduce your (employee level, employee name).");

string? readResult = Console.ReadLine();
string? info = "";

string title = "";


if (readResult != null)
    info = readResult;

var employeeInfo = info.Split(",");
var employeeLevel = Convert.ToInt32(employeeInfo[0]);
string employeeName = employeeInfo[1];

switch (employeeLevel)
{
    case > 400:
        title = "Senior Manager";
        break;

    case > 300:
        title = "Manager";

        break;

    case > 200:
        title = "Senior Associate";
        break;

    case > 100:
        title = "Junior Associate";
        break;

    default:
        title = "Associate";
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine($"{employeeName}, {title}");


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info)) 
Console.WriteLine("Please enter you info in the correct format. (employee level, employee name");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling the `Int32.TryParse` method. It will return a `bool` to indicate whether the input was parsed successfully and, if so, provide the converted value via an `out` parameter.

```cs
int employeeLevel;

if (int.TryParse(employeeInfo[0], out employeeLevel))
{
    // The conversion was successful and the output is contained in employeeLevel.
}
else
{
    // The conversion was unsuccessful.
}
```

Comment: thanks it still does'nt quite solve the problem but thats good. i still get an error message if the format isnt right. if i insert letters insted of numbers it gives an error message

Comment: @MónicaAlípio, that code certainly isn't going to generate an error message if the user enters letters, so if an exception is being thrown somewhere else then your code elsewhere must be wrong. Of course, if the user enters invalid data then you should be displaying an appropriate error message and there's obviously no data that you can use later. That's why you use an `if` block and only use the data if the input was valid. The code I provided simply prevents an exception being thrown. You still have to implement appropriate logic besides that.